# How to get full current date and time in Vue.js without writing massive JavaScript lines

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to print "Last updated: 6/12/2019 1:30 PM" in Vue.js. 
I have the current year but I want the full date and time. Here's what I have so far

```
<div id="app">
Last updated: {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}
</div>
```

Comment: You can make your life alot easier and just use momentJS https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use: `new Date().toLocaleString()`, it gives you `"6/13/2019, 9:40:40 AM"`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can either use JavaScript `new Date()` methods [check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) , or you can install [vue-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment) via npm .

Installation :

```
npm install moment
```

Require the plugin :

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

Display Date :

```
<span>Last updated: {{ moment("D/M/YYYY h:mm A") }}</span>
```

Comment: This is what I was trying before but it does not work. Although I installed moment it says there is a problem with the plugin : Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));

Comment: @ibeefymcwhatnow can you list your error ? vue-moment should work properly first.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Comment: I am certain that I installed moment

Comment: @ibeefymcwhatnow i've updated my Solution try the new Edit.

Comment: Thank you for answering but now I get a different error saying: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.moment is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

It is a very simple getting current date time in vue.js.

You can use: `{{ new Date() }}`, it gives you `Sat Dec 05 2020 12:51:25`

Date() will provide us full date and time with timezone.

But you want to make better format like 'dd-mm-yyyy' in vue.js, then you use moment

```
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.prototype.moment = moment
```

Then in your template, simply use

```
{{ moment(new Date()).format('DD-MM-YYYY') }}
```

Output:

```
05-12-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

```
showDate()
{
   const dateObj = new Date();
   const currentDate = dateObj.getDate()+"/"+dateObj.getMonth()+"/"+dateObj.getFullYear();
   console.log(currentDate);
},
```

use this process to get current date in any required format